# How to resolve parsing: Invalid token error in Dax query

Tags: sql, dax

I am trying to get the value from below DAX query in sql but getting below error, could some guide me how to resolve this error.

I am very new to DAX let me know if you have any idea, here **Output** is table name.

**ERROR- Query (1, 29) The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 1, Offset 29,  .**

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (     
'Output'[Filename],   
'Output'[CreatedDate],            
FILTER(VALUES('Output'[CreatedDate]),
('Output'[CreatedDate] >= DATEVALUE("11/06/2021 1:00:00 AM"))),   
"Filecount", countrows('Output')             
)Order by 'Output'[CreatedDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

After merge the query in single line & removing the white space from query it's worked perfectly.

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ('Output'[Filename],'Output'[CreatedDate],FILTER(VALUES('Output'[CreatedDate]),('Output'[CreatedDate] >= DATEVALUE("11/06/2021 1:00:00 AM"))),"Filecount", countrows('Output'))Order by 'Output'[CreatedDate]
```